# Insert image in database using php

Tags: php

This is my code in insert page. While I run the code its give error of undefine indext at line no 14. I want to upload image in database and retrieve from database.

```
<?php
$db_handle = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$db_handle)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("example");


    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $last=$_POST['last'];
    $hobbies=implode(',',$_POST['hobbies']);
    $study= implode(',', $_POST['study']);
    $image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    //inserting data order
    $order = "INSERT INTO emp (F_name,L_name,Hobbies,Study,Image) VALUES('$first','$last','$hobbies','$study','$image')";

    //declare in the order variable
    $result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
    if($result)
    {
        echo("<BR>Input data is succeed");
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='main.php'>Back to main page</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<BR>Input data is fail");
    }

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're file `<input>` has a name attribute of `image`? Sidenote: [please don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1612146)

Comment: What's the error? Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprectated.

Comment: You should start with the manual (check the `['error']` value): http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: yes name attribute is image

Comment: As an aside - You will need to move the uploaded file to another store - the `tmp_name` is where the file is put temporarily - you should put it somewhere else with `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: What will happen when `$first = "'; DROP TABLE emp;--"`

Comment: i got thnks for your help

Comment: @DainisAbols It won't drop the table that's for sure, `mysql_query` doesn't support multiple statements.  Not that *SQL* injection isn't an issue - just that there's probably a better example :)